# unable to use npm lighthouse module in GitHub action

Tags: npm, github-actions, lighthouse

I am trying to run the npm lighthouse [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse) on a step defined in a GitHub action, but everytime I run the action I encounter an error that looks like this

```
Thu, 13 Jul 2023 08:42:59 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher:error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:37227
Thu, 13 Jul 2023 08:42:59 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher:error Logging contents of /tmp/lighthouse.uqY5io0/chrome-err.log
Thu, 13 Jul 2023 08:42:59 GMT LH:ChromeLauncher:error [1821:1821:0713/084240.896601:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[1821:1821:0713/084240.905253:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

and here is my github action

```
...
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.5.2
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: set CMD based on device
        id: cmd
        run: |
           cmd=--form-factor=mobile
            if [ ${{ inputs.device }} == "device" ]; then
              cmd=--preset=desktop
            fi
            echo "cmd=$cmd" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT    
      - name: Run Lighthouse
        id: lighthouseCheck
        run: |
          npm i -g lighthouse
          echo "cmd value is ${{ steps.cmd.outputs.cmd }}"
          lighthouse ${{ inputs.url }} --port=8080 ${{ steps.cmd.outputs.cmd }} --output=json --output-path=${{ env.ARTIFACT_PATH_JSON_PATH }}
```